# Regarding the for each loop

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, each

```
def exit
  @result = 0
  @correct_answer = Question.pluck(:correct_answer).first
  @selected_answer = Question.pluck(:selected_answer).first
  @id = Question.pluck(:id)
  @questions = Question.all
  #binding.pry
  @questions.each do |i|
    if @correct_answer == @selected_answer
      @result += 1
    else
      @result -= 1
    end
  end
end
```

I am using this code after implementing .each loop my if conditions does not executed it always go true block

how can I fix this issue

Comment: Don't name a method `exit` unless you understand what you're doing. You'll create a confusing script since `exit` is already an existing method name.

Answer (score 0):

In these two lines:

```
@correct_answer = Question.pluck(:correct_answer).first
@selected_answer = Question.pluck(:selected_answer).first
```

You are pulling the first corrected and selected answers out of the database.

When you go through the each loop, you are only ever comparing whether these two match - not the answers associated with the current question. So the result will always be the same.

I think this is what you are after:

```
def exit
  @result = 0
  @questions = Question.all
  @questions.each do |question|
    if question.correct_answer == question.selected_answer
      @result += 1
    else
      @result -= 1
    end
  end
  @result
end
```

Comment: i want to check all questions correct_answers and selected_answer wether they are equal or not

Comment: I think you don't understand how each works - http://docs.ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_array.html#Array.each

Comment: @JassaMahal what is exactly in Question class ? How its looks like.

Comment: it has two name correct_answer field and selected_answer and i want to comapre those fields  using n number of questions

Comment: If Question class and method all return Array ov Objects and this object have those methods (correct_answer and selected_answer). In that case is this answer correct.

Comment: i already put correct_answers in db and selected_answer are coming from view after selecting a radio button and i wan to compare those

Comment: Perhaps if we can all find a large brick wall, we could all run at it very fast and see what happens.

Comment: actually i want to comapre all question correct and selected_answer and after imlementing my code it gives me only number of question not the exact output

Comment: its not looping all question  this code computes only one question